# Can I get the full query that a PreparedStatement is about to execute?

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm working with `PreparedStatement` with MySQL Server.

example:

```
String myQuery = "select id from user where name = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt  = sqlConnection.prepareStatement(myQuery);
stmt.setString(1, "test");
stmt.executeQUery();
ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
```

How can I receive the **full SQL query** that is about to be executed on the `MySQL Server`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not mandated by the JDBC spec, but several JDBC drivers let the `toString` of a `PreparedStatement` return sort-of the query that will be run, and MySQL's Connector/J happens to have this behavior (or at least it did a few years ago).

```
String myQuery = "select id from user where name = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt  = sqlConnection.prepareStatement(myQuery);
stmt.setString(1, "test");
System.out.println(stmt); // May do what you want!
```

Comment: thank you! stmt.toString() resolved the issue.

Comment: If stmt.toString() doesn't work, try following the solution provided in this article:
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2002/jw-0125-overpower.html?page=1

Comment: It works on Postgres driver (9.1) too.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot really get out the query that will be executed but there are logging APIs that will log database calls for you such as [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/) and [p6spy](http://www.p6spy.com/).

Answer (score 3):

You can't, as Java isn't responsible for constructing it. Prepared statements are supported within MySQL, so Java sends the actual parameterized SQL ("select id from user where name = ?") straight to MySQL along with the parameters

Comment: Actually some JDBC drivers do the work on the client side and send a fully-parameterized query to the server (I don't know which way the MySQL driver uses). There is no standardized way to get the "complete" SQL statement anyway.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: MySQL Connector/J 3.1 and newer will user server-side prepared statements.

Answer (score 3):

I can tell you what it is.  If you're using MySQL 4.1 or newer with Connector/J 3.1 or newer, it will be something like:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM 'select id from user where name = ?'
SET @a = 'test'
EXECUTE stmt USING @a
```

This is because MySQL supports [server-side prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

(More likely it uses the binary protocol, but this code is just to make a point)

Answer (score 3):

Hi I implement the following code which fetch SQL from **PreparedStatement** . No need to use any jar and Driver .

```
public void printSqlStatement(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, String sql) throws SQLException{
        String[] sqlArrya= new String[preparedStatement.getParameterMetaData().getParameterCount()];
        try {
               Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\?");
               Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sql);
               StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
               int indx = 1;  // Parameter begin with index 1
               while (matcher.find()) {
             matcher.appendReplacement(sb,String.valueOf(sqlArrya[indx]));
               }
               matcher.appendTail(sb);
              System.err.println("Executing Query [" + sb.toString() + "] with Database[" + "] ...");
               } catch (Exception ex) {
                   System.err.println("Executing Query [" + sql + "] with Database[" +  "] ...");
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach from all answers here,

If you are familiar with Debugging options in Eclipse. You may try the following:

1. Set a Breakpoint at `stmt.executeQUery();`
2. Right click your application, say `Debug As` select `Java Application` (or Whatever applicable in your case i.e. may be SpringBoot App etc.
3. Perform step that gets you to code mentioned in the Question.
4. If you check `Variables tab` in `Debug Perspective` of Eclipse, you will find variables like `myQuery` , `stmt` (according to your code)
5. Whatever you see as value of `stmt` would be the full SQL query you need.

Also, if you don't want to keep looking at this variable always you may try `Java Logging` and Print your Full SQL query in Logs.